# How to generate AST from Java source-code?

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction

As far as I know, the only way to parse Java source-code into an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) is to use the [Java Compiler Tree API](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/09/16/hacking-javac): com.sun.source.tree

I have two questions:

1. What JDKs support com.sun.source.tree?
2. Is there a portable replacement that works for all JDKs?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Eclipse uses a different version of the Java model with their own parser, and there might be a way to reuse that for general parsing.

Comment: What do you mean by "support" in your first question?  Are you asking which versions of Java from which vendors contain the com.sun.source.tree package?  I would imagine only Sun's does.  If you want to parse source code with another JDK (say, IBM's), then a standalone parser library is probably necessary.

Comment: @Brett, I know that com.sun.source.tree was only introduced in JDK6. I'm wondering if all non-Sun JDKs support this API.

Comment: com.sun is not portable.  It may exist in other JDKs but do not count on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can possibly take the tools.jar and use it.  [javac is open source](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/) so you can just grab that code (assuming you can deal with the license).  [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) has grammars for Java as well.

Comment: Redistributing tools.jar: good point! OpenJDK's classpath exception makes for a great license.

Comment: google-java-format uses `com.google.errorprone:javac-shaded` to get the AST. `javac-shaded` embeds OpenJDK parser in itself. Example can be found at `JavaInputAstVisitor.java` in google-java-format.

Comment: Entry point is [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/parser/ParserFactory.java#L53)

Answer (score 29):

Regarding your second question, there are dozens of Java parsers available in addition to Sun's.  Here is a small sample:

- Eclipse's [org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/package-tree.html) package.
- [Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/) outputs a very nice annotated parse tree with type information and variable binding (and uses Eclipse's parser internally)
- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is a parser-generator, but there are grammars for Java available
- [javaparser](http://javaparser.github.io/javaparser/) (which I have not used)

My best advice is to try each of them to see which works best for your needs.

Comment: What is the difference between Eclipse's jdt DOM and Spoon?

Comment: The actual AST classes are roughly analogous, but Spoon's parse tree includes semantic information like variable binding without requiring a massive IDE infrastructure to be running. One can parse and analyze Java files by simply adding one jar file to the classpath.

Answer (score 7):

I've used Eclipse's AST parser. I found it to be pretty good (well it was part of an Eclipse plug-in so it did make sense to use it). See [Exploring Eclipse's ASTParser](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ast/).

Comment: Here is last WebArchive for the link above. https://web.archive.org/web/20090801122725/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ast/

Answer (score 3):

A working, simple to use Java Parser is... [JavaParser](http://javaparser.github.io/javaparser/). The project has been active for some years already. While it was initially hosted on Google code it is now available on GitHub: https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser

It is quite simple to use and the number of dependencies is small. It is also available on Maven.

It has been used for a few years, so it works quite well and permits to parse also comments, to change the AST and regenerate the code.

Comment: Thanks for updating the link to the project (it has been moved a few months ago and in the meantime I became a contributor to this project :D)

Answer (score 1):

It is not the only way.

See our  [Java Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html), which is a full featured Java parser built on top of the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).  It parses Java, and builds ASTs as internal data structures.

The point of DMS is that it provides a huge variety of *additional* useful machinery (attribute grammars, symbol tables, flow analysis, AST manipulation including access and update, as well as source-to-source transformations) to analyze and transform that AST into results and/or modified source code.   If you get "just" a Java parser (e.g., JavaCC  + Java grammar) you will, IMHO, not be able to do a lot with it.  DMS makes it possible to do a lot, without having to invent all that extra machinery yourself.

If you really don't want to use the extra machinery DMS provides, it will [dump the tree as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378997/120163).

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across [**Jexast**](https://github.com/monperrus/jexast), an extraction of the [JDT's ASTParser](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTParser.html) to [work independent of Eclipse](http://www.monperrus.net/martin/jexast) (it depends on `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.**`).

I haven't tried it yet, but it does seem interesting.