# Get the class declaration

Tags: java, eclipse

Is possible to get the whole information (with `modifiers`,  `extends` and `implements`) of a class declaration through an AST???

I want to get a structure like this:

```
[ modifiers ] class ClassName [ extends SuperClassName ] [ implements InterfaceNames ] {
```

Thanks for the information!

Comment: you mean by reflection ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classModifiers.html

Comment: How about giving some more information, and try an answer with it? It would quality ...

Answer (score 0):

In Java it's quite hard to get the value but you can get things like:-

`Class Modifiers`:-  If you able to make Object of that class than it's a Public class else others
`Extends`:-  You have to check Overridden methods.
`Implements`:-  You have to check the Abstract methods in the class to know. else that class will be Abstract class
.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need reflection as such.

use [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) API

`Class clsObj = Class.forName("yourclas");`

methods like,

```
getModifiers();
getSuperClass();
getInterfaces();
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by TheWhiteRabbit, you can use reflection starting from the [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class or maybe you are looking for a code parser such as [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/).
Please note that your question seems to already have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967987/how-to-generate-ast-from-java-source-code).

Comment: I know how to parse code using AST and how to get the information of the class using the node "TypeDeclaration". The only information I want to get is the class declaration, just the "title". Doing .getName I only get the ClassName and I want the modifiers, extends and implements as well. Have any idea?

Comment: It should be nice if you would tell which AST framework you are using! Eclipse JDT? It seems not to be simple Java reflection. Am I wrong. I must admit my experience with JTD is limited but shouldn't the methods superInterfaces() and getSuperclass()  help you?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the Eclipse API for AST and the methods superInterfaces() and getSuperclass() are useful but is there any way to get the whole class declaration information in one step?

I want to get something like this:

public class GetInfo extends AbstractHandler {