# Writing a Sonar plugin to measure class usage

Tags: sonarqube

I need to write a Sonar plugin to keep track of the library classes that are used the most in a project.

So far I read the [Coding a Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Coding+a+Plugin) guide but I am a little bit confused. Does Sonar provide any facility to perform analysis (Something like parsing of Java code, creation of Abstract Syntax Trees, ...) or should I look for an external tool that does it and use Sonar only as a reporting tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonar provides a framework for publishing your own code analysis results into to Sonar so that they are in a single place. Although it does some analysis of it's own it mostly relies on other static code analysis tools and just integrates them into the lifecycle, e.g., test coverage can be implemented by cobertura or clover.

Sounds to me though like you just to get a measure of the [Afferent couplings](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions) which can be configured for a single library. Not sure how you would manage it for cross library dependencies as most of the plugins work by using instrumenting the code at compile time which would not be possible for classes already in a jar.

If you just want to generate an AST then you should [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967987/how-to-generate-ast-from-java-source-code).

Comment: Actually I need something more complex than afferent couplings. Can you recommend me a good tool to generate an AST from Java source code?

Comment: There is a similar question on how to generate an AST here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967987/how-to-generate-ast-from-java-source-code